# adding .annotate foreign key in objects does not give distinct result

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

When i run following query its working fine

```
    query= UserOrder.objects.filter(order_date__range=(
        Request['from'], Request['to'])).values('user_id__username','user_id__email').annotate(
            total_no_of_order=Count("pk")).annotate(total=Sum('total_cost'))
```

But i also want to know the number of services related to order

```
.annotate(total_no_of_services=Count("userorderservice__pk"))
```

by adding above code in query `total_no_of_order` and `total_cost` getting changed too and by putting `distinct=True` in `total_cost`  its only considering for single unique `total_cost` value

Modles.py

```
class UserOrder(models.Model):
    order_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(AppUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    total_cost = models.FloatField()
    ...


class UserOrderService(models.Model):
    order_id = models.ForeignKey(UserOrder, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

Comment: It woulld help if you could provide an examplary result. Do you need a list of counts per user or per order or per service? "total_no_of_order" seems not hepful in relation to UserOrder - I would expect this to be 1 for all UserObject rows, and I would expect this to be different for User rows. However, you start of with UserObjects...

Answer (score 0):

A **UserOrder** can have many **UserOrderService** instances.

Therefore, the correct way to COUNT is:

```
.annotate(total_no_of_services=Count("userorderservice_set"))
```

Please have a look at [reverse relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects)

Comment: this doesnt work.     django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'userorderservice_set' into field.

Comment: Isn't it going to be `user_order_service_set`? TBH, better to give the FK relation a `related_name` so it's clear what you're referring to.

Comment: `Count("useroderservice__pk")` is correct. The suffix `_set` is only used for attributes (like `my_user_order.userorderservice_set.pk`) but not used in args/kwargs of the ORM. Your observation that UserOrder can have many UserOrderService instances, however, is important. Depending on the relations, the resulting QuerySets can have "duplicates". `distinct` might not always be the solution but rather to start from a different Model.